# Sorting a list of objects with the order of an List of object-Ids

Tags: java, list, sorting

This is what I have:

```
class Person {
  Integer id;
  String name;
}

// A list of persons:
List<Person> persons

// Now I have something like this:
List<Integer> ids  // where the ids are stored in an specific order
```

Basically I wanna sort the persons list in the same order like the ids.

Is there a better way then use like two loops and create a new Person-List?

regards && tia

noircc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Collections.sort` using a custom `Comparator` as shown below. The comparator gets the ids of the persons being compared and works out in which order they appear in the ids list:

```
List<Person> persons = ...;
final List<Integer> ids = ...;

Collections.sort(persons, new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        int index1 = ids.indexOf(p1.getId());
        int index2 = ids.indexOf(p2.getId());
        return index1 < index2 ? -1 : (index1 == index2 ? 0 : 1);
    }
});
```

Note: this code assumes that the ids of all persons in the list will appear in the ids list.

Comment: What's the complexity?..

Comment: Collections.sort is O(nlogn), but for each comparison there are two O(n) index lookups, so not very efficient, but at least there are no temporary collections being created.

Answer (score -1):

1. Map each of the `ids` into its index: `Map<Integer, Integer> idToIndex`;
2. Run the following loop.

---

```
for (int i = 0, size = persons.length - 1; i < size; ++i) {
  var targetIndex = idToIndex.get(persons.get(i).id);
  if (targetIndex != i) {
    persons[i] <-> persons[targetIndex];
  }
}
```

Comment: ...and C++, too :) `<->` means "swap", guess that's intuitive.

Comment: -1 this won't work because you are swapping persons and you might end up skipping a person you have swapped. e.g. try your algorithm with persons=[2,5,1,3] and ids=[1,3,5,2]. It incorrectly gives 3,1,5,2 because it swapped 2 with 3.